# I'm getting no errors when using react on vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and I'm trying to learn react.

This what it shows me:
[image: how it looks like when I write it]

This code can't run because I don't access to item, but it show me no error...

I started watch video about react and this how it supposed to look like, as it on his computer:
[image: what I saw in the video]

EDIT: I've installed eslint https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

and now it show me the error.

Comment: install the `eslint` vs code  extension

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you are missing eslint. Once you install eslint https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint, go to the file again it should start showing the errors

Comment: thank you! I installed `eslint` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `item` is not defined. You need to define that previously.

Also, in your context the `key` prop on your first div is not needed, as you're not looping through an array of elements and rendering DOM elements for them.

Comment: It's not about why it is not working.. The question is about why the VS Code doesn't highlight errors...

Answer (score -1):

make the following change in the first line of the Card component:
 `const Card=({item})=>{ ... }`